# Difference Between Pointer(*) And Reference(&)

Tags: c++

I use Reference(&) here,but the a didn't change.Why?
While i use Pointer(*) the value have changed.

```
int all=0; 
void call_from_thread(int & a)  
{
   a = 5;
}

int main() 
{
    thread s = thread(call_from_thread, all);
    s.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Another program,in this case, i also use Reference(&),but the value have changed. Why the value a in thread didn't change?

```
void Func3(int &x)
{
    x = x + 10;
}

int main() {

    int n = 0;
    Func3(n);
    cout << “n = ” << n << endl; // n = 10
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread  3) - Yeah, it's annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::thread` constructor makes copies of its parameters during the thread creation step.... ordinary references don't survive the trip, and the `call_from_thread` function receives a reference to the copy.

Details can be found in the Standard.  The `thread::thread` constructor behavior is described as

> Constructs an object of type thread. The new thread of execution executes `INVOKE(DECAY_COPY(std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY_COPY(std::forward<Args>(args))...)` with the calls to
>   `DECAY_COPY` being evaluated in the constructing thread.

The exact definition of `DECAY_COPY` is quite complex, but as the name suggests, it ignores references and makes a value copy.

A simple workaround is to use `std::ref`.

```
thread s = thread(call_from_thread, std::ref(all));
```

This keeps a pointer through the copies, and only resolves to the actual target when the reference parameter is bound.